# Error importing MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm learning Spark(Pyspark) and while trying to import MLLIB libraries, I came across this strange error that MulticlassClassificationEvaluator cannot be imported:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-0033401bce6e> in <module>()
4 from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
----> 5 from pyspark.ml.evaluation import MulticlassClassificationEvaluator

ImportError: cannot import name MulticlassClassificationEvaluator
```

Comment: Do you use development branch / 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT? If not It is not weird since `MulticlassClassificationEvaluator` is not available in PySpark <= 1.4.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the problem. I was using spark-1.4.0 which obviously has no implementation of MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.